# hide empty images with same id in slider

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, show-hide

How can I hide one or two empty input images inside of slider?
I tried with this code and I thought that it worked because just showed one image when another two are empty, but when I insert a second or the three images always shows only the first one, where is my error? can you help me..

Here the code:

libraries js:

```
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.nerveSlider.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".myslider").show();
    $(".myslider").startslider({
        slideTransitionSpeed: 900,
        slideImageScaleMode: "fit",
        sliderKeepAspectRatio: true,
        slideTransitionEasing: "easeOutExpo",
        slidesDraggable: true,
        sliderResizable: true,
        showDots:true,
        });
    });
</script>

<?php 
    try {
        $query = "SELECT id, foto1, foto2, foto3 FROM FOTOS WHERE id = ?";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare( $query );
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $_REQUEST['id']);    
        $stmt->execute();
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $id = $row['id'];
    }
    catch(PDOException $exception)
    { 
        echo "Error: " . $exception->getMessage();
    }
?>

<div class="myslider" id="<?php echo $id; ?>">
    <?php 
        if (!empty($row['foto1'])) 
        { 
            echo '<img src="assets/img/'.$row["foto1"].'" alt="imagen 1" style="max-width:600px; max-height:400px;" />';
        }
        else if (!empty($row['foto2'])) 
        { 
            echo '<img src="assets/img/'.$row["foto2"].'" alt="imagen 2" style="max-width:600px; max-height:400px;" />';
        }
        else if (!empty($row['foto3'])) 
        { 
            echo '<img src="assets/img/'.$row["foto3"].'" alt="imagen 3" style="max-width:600px; max-height:400px;" />';
        }
    ?> 
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to do this with jquery or php?

Comment: You're asking about jQuery but you've posted PHP. Pick one. :-) If it's jQuery you're after, show us HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your PHP code;

an `if-else if-else if` group will only process until the first `if` or `else if` check that returns true; it will then process that statement and skip the rest of the `else if` statements. So to fix it just replace your `else if`s with `if`s - like this:

```
...snip...
<div class="myslider" id="<?php echo $id; ?>">
    <?php 
        if (!empty($row['foto1'])) 
        { 
            echo '<img src="assets/img/'.$row["foto1"].'" alt="imagen 1" style="max-width:600px; max-height:400px;" />';
        }
        if (!empty($row['foto2'])) 
        { 
            echo '<img src="assets/img/'.$row["foto2"].'" alt="imagen 2" style="max-width:600px; max-height:400px;" />';
        }
        if (!empty($row['foto3'])) 
        { 
            echo '<img src="assets/img/'.$row["foto3"].'" alt="imagen 3" style="max-width:600px; max-height:400px;" />';
        }
    ?> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="myslider" id="<?php echo $id; ?>">
<?php 
    if (!empty($row['foto1'])) { 
        echo '<img src="assets/img/'.$row["foto1"].'" alt="imagen 1" style="max-width:600px; max-height:400px;" />';
    } else {
        echo '';
    }

    if (!empty($row['foto2'])) { 
        echo '<img src="assets/img/'.$row["foto2"].'" alt="imagen 2" style="max-width:600px; max-height:400px;" />';
    } else {
        echo '';
    }

    if (!empty($row['foto3'])) { 
        echo '<img src="assets/img/'.$row["foto3"].'" alt="imagen 3" style="max-width:600px; max-height:400px;" />';
    } else {
        echo '';
    }
?>
```